# How do I split a flac with a cue?

Tags: command-line, audio, gui, flac

I've got a full album flac and a cue file for it. How can I split this into a flac per track?

I'm a KDE user, so I would prefer a KDE/Qt way. I would like to see command line and other GUI answers as well, but they are not my preferred method.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/251362/split-monkeyaudio-ape-cue-log-of-whole-audio-cd-into-mp3-of-individual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have cue set to use `k3b` in in the filetype settings, `k3b` will automatically split the file if you open the cue file, and allow you to re-rip.

Answer (score 123):

Shnsplit can read a cue file directly, which also means it can access the other data from the cue file (not just the breakpoints) and generate nicer filenames than `split-*.flac`:

```
shnsplit -f file.cue -t %n-%t -o flac file.flac
```

Granted, this makes it more difficult to use cuetag.sh if the original flac file is in the same directory.

Comment: Fellow debian users: `sudo apt-get install cuetools shntool`

Comment: You probably also want to tag the files with `cuetag file.cue [0-9]*.flac`

Comment: I also needed: `sudo apt-get install flac`

Comment: cuetools already depends on flac, so …

Comment: On Debian 10 there is a bug with 24 bits flacs. It won't split. It works fine on 16 bits files though.

Comment: I did this and my single flac files are not playable.

Comment: On Arch you can install from shntool from AUR, e.g. `yay -S shntool`

Comment: It is important to have track number (`%n`) in the `-t` option of `shnsplit` in order `cuetag file.cue [0-9]*.flac` to succeed. Without this newly extracted tracks will have wrong metadata, since it will not know how to match tracks described in the cue file with the tracks in the separate files.

Answer (score 31):

[Flacon](http://flacon.github.io/) is an intuitive open-source GUI that does exactly that: split a FLAC with a CUE.

> Flacon extracts individual tracks from one big audio file containing the entire album of music and saves them as separate audio files. To do this, it uses information from the appropriate CUE file.

It supports among other things:

> Supported input formats: WAV, FLAC, APE, WavPack, True Audio (TTA).
>
> Supported out formats: FLAC, WAV, WavPack, AAC, OGG or MP3.
>
> Automatic character set detection for CUE files.

To use it you only need to open the `*.cue` file with Flacon. It should then automatically detect the big `*.flac` file (if not, you can specify this manually), and then you should select Flac output format (and optionally configure the encoder), and start the conversion process.

[image: Flacon v5.4.0]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: still updated in 2017

Comment: I don't like to use UI for things I can do on the terminal, but I was struggling with an album, and this was the only way of splitting the files. You deserve a beer now man

Comment: Unfortunately, Flacon doesn't support 32/192 format. I have a Vinyl Rip which came as a wavepack in 32/192 format and Flacon throws an error that the resolution is too high.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've been looking for a tool exactly like this for a long time now. Excellent recommendation.

Answer (score 24):

I only know a CLI way. You will need cuetools and shntool.

```
cuebreakpoints file.cue | shnsplit -o flac file.flac
cuetag.sh file.cue "split-*".flac
```

Comment: Thanks for this Kambus. I've been using `cuebreakpoints file.cue | shnsplit -o flac file.flac` for a long time. The 2nd bit is going to help a lot!

Comment: `cuetag` seems to break on filenames containing spaces but after removing them it worked.

Answer (score 9):

if high-quality files are being used, shnsplit is happily erroring out with

```
shnsplit: error: m:ss.ff format can only be used with CD-quality files
```

fortunately the flac binary supports --skip=mm:ss.ss and --until=mm:ss.ss so a script can use cuebreakpoints like this:

```
[..]
time[0]="00:00.00"
c=1
for ts in $(cuebreakpoints "${cue_file}"); do
    time[${c}]=${ts}
    c=$((c+1))
done
time[${c}]='-0'
for ((i=0;i<$((${#time[@]}-1));i++)); do
    trackno=$(($i+1))
    TRACKNUMBER="$(printf %02d ${trackno})"
    title="$(cueprint --track-number ${trackno} -t '%t' "${cue_file}")"
    flac --silent --exhaustive-model-search --skip=${time[$i]} --until=${time[$(($i+1))]} --tag=ARTIST="${ARTIST}" --tag=ALBUM="${ALBUM}" --tag=DATE="${DATE}" --tag=TITLE="${title}" --tag=TRACKNUMBER="${TRACKNUMBER}" "${aud_file}" --output-name="${TRACKNUMBER}-${title}.flac"
done
```

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a PHP script:

```php
<?php
$s_cue = $argv[1];
$a_cue = file($s_cue);
$n_row = -1;
foreach ($a_cue as $s_row) {
   $s_trim = trim($s_row);
   $a_row = str_getcsv($s_trim, ' ');
   if (preg_match('/^FILE\s/', $s_row) == 1) {
      $s_file = $a_row[1];
   }
   if (preg_match('/^\s+TRACK\s/', $s_row) == 1) {
      $n_row++;
      $a_table[$n_row]['track'] = $a_row[1];
   }
   if (preg_match('/^\s+TITLE\s/', $s_row) == 1) {
      $a_table[$n_row]['title'] = $a_row[1];
   }
   if (preg_match('/^\s+PERFORMER\s/', $s_row) == 1) {
      $a_table[$n_row]['artist'] = $a_row[1];
   }
   if (preg_match('/^\s+INDEX\s/', $s_row) == 1) {
      $s_dur = $a_row[2];
      $a_frame = sscanf($s_dur, '%d:%d:%d', $n_min, $n_sec, $n_fra);
      $n_index = $n_min * 60 + $n_sec + $n_fra / 75;
      $a_table[$n_row]['ss'] = $n_index;
      if ($n_row > 0) {
         $a_table[$n_row - 1]['to'] = $n_index;
      }
   }
}
$a_table[$n_row]['to'] = 10 * 60 * 60;
foreach ($a_table as $m_row) {
   $a_cmd = [
      'ffmpeg',
      '-i', $s_file,
      '-ss', $m_row['ss'],
      '-to', $m_row['to'],
      '-metadata', 'artist=' . $m_row['artist'],
      '-metadata', 'title=' . $m_row['title'],
      '-metadata', 'track=' . $m_row['track'],
      $m_row['track'] . ' ' . $m_row['title'] . '.m4a'
   ];
   $a_esc = array_map('escapeshellarg', $a_cmd);
   $s_esc = implode(' ', $a_esc);
   system($s_esc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a project that works for several input files: [split2flac](https://github.com/ftrvxmtrx/split2flac)

From the project description:

> split2flac splits one big APE/FLAC/TTA/WV/WAV audio image (or a
>   collection of such files, recursively) with CUE sheet into
>   FLAC/M4A/MP3/OGG_VORBIS/WAV tracks with tagging, renaming, charset
>   conversion of cue sheet, album cover images. It also uses
>   configuration file, so no need to pass a lot of arguments every time,
>   only an input file. Should work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 1):

I found `mac` (which is the command that `shntool` used for decoding APE files) is way less tolerant than `ffmpeg` if the source file contains minor errors.

Normally `ffmpeg` would still convert the file completely while `mac` very likely throws an error during the processing.

So I ended up writing a script for spliting APE file by parsing the CUE file and converting the APE file to FLAC files separated by titles using ffmpeg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import subprocess as subp
import sys
import os
from os.path import splitext, basename
import random
import glob

records = []
filename = ""
album=''
alb_artist=''
codec = 'flac'
ffmpeg_exec = 'ffmpeg'
encodingList = ('utf-8','euc-kr', 'shift-jis', 'cp936', 'big5')

filecontent = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
for enc in encodingList:
    try:
        lines = filecontent.decode(enc).split('\n')
        encoding = enc
        break
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        if enc == encodingList[-1]:
            raise e
        else:
            pass

for l in lines:
    a = l.split()
    if not a:
        continue
    if a[0] == "FILE":
        filename = ' '.join(a[1:-1]).strip('\'"')
    elif a[0]=='TRACK':
        records.append({})
        records[-1]['index'] = a[1]
    elif a[0]=='TITLE':
        if len(records)>0:
            records[-1]['title'] = ' '.join(a[1:]).strip('\'"')
        else:
            album =  ' '.join(a[1:]).strip('\'"')
    elif a[0]=='INDEX' and a[1]=='01':
        timea = a[2].split(':')
        if len(timea) == 3 and int(timea[0]) >= 60:
            timea.insert(0, str(int(timea[0])/60))
            timea[1] = str(int(timea[1])%60)
        times = '{0}.{1}'.format(':'.join(timea[:-1]), timea[-1])
        records[-1]['start'] = times
    elif a[0]=='PERFORMER':
        if len(records)>1:
            records[-1]['artist'] = ' '.join(a[1:]).strip('\'"')
        else:
            alb_artist = ' '.join(a[1:]).strip('\'"')

for i, j in enumerate(records):
    try:
        j['stop'] = records[i+1]['start']
    except IndexError:
        pass

if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    tmpname = splitext(basename(sys.argv[1]))[0]+splitext(filename)[1]
    if os.path.exists(tmpname):
        filename = tmpname
        del tmpname
    else:
        for ext in ('.ape', '.flac', '.wav', '.mp3'):
            tmpname = splitext(filename)[0] + ext
            if os.path.exists(tmpname):
                filename = tmpname
                break

if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    raise IOError("Can't not find file: {0}".format(filename))

fstat = os.stat(filename)
atime = fstat.st_atime
mtime = fstat.st_mtime

records[-1]['stop'] = '99:59:59'

if filename.lower().endswith('.flac'):
    tmpfile = filename
else:
    tmpfile = splitext(filename)[0] + str(random.randint(10000,90000)) + '.flac'

try:
    if filename != tmpfile:
        ret = subp.call([ffmpeg_exec, '-hide_banner', '-y', '-i', filename, 
            '-c:a', codec,'-compression_level','12','-f','flac',tmpfile])

        if ret != 0:
            raise SystemExit('Converting failed.')

    for i in records:
        output = i['index'] +' - '+ i['title']+'.flac'
        commandline = [ffmpeg_exec, '-hide_banner', 
        '-y', '-i', tmpfile,
        '-c', 'copy', 
        '-ss', i['start'], '-to', i['stop'],
        '-metadata', u'title={0}'.format(i['title']), 
        '-metadata', u'artist={0}'.format(i.get('artist', '')),
        '-metadata', u'performer={0}'.format(i.get('artist', '')),
        '-metadata', u'album={0}'.format(album), 
        '-metadata', 'track={0}/{1}'.format(i['index'], len(records)), 
        '-metadata', u'album_artist={0}'.format(alb_artist), 
        '-metadata', u'composer={0}'.format(alb_artist), 
        '-metadata', 'encoder=Meow', 
        '-write_id3v1', '1', 
        output]
        ret = subp.call(commandline)
        if ret == 0:
            os.utime(output, (atime, mtime))
finally:
    if os.path.isfile(tmpfile):
        os.remove(tmpfile)
```

Comment: You might want to change `if os.path.isfile(tmpfile)` to `if tmpfile != filename and os.path.isfile(tmpfile)` to avoid deleting the original file on error.

Comment: The condition for setting the track artist must be if `len(records)>0`.

Answer (score 1):

**`shntool` on Ubuntu 14.04**

`snhtool` is missing the `mac` (Monkey's Audio Console) executable dependency, and the only package I could find it was in the `flacon` PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:flacon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y flacon shntool
shntool split -f *.cue -o flac -t '%n - %p - %t' *.ape
```

`flacon` is a GUI for `shntool`, but it comes with all the codecs it needs... otherwise I got the error:

```
shnsplit: warning: failed to read data from input file using format: [ape]
shnsplit:          + you may not have permission to read file: [example.ape]
shnsplit:          + arguments may be incorrect for decoder: [mac]
shnsplit:          + verify that the decoder is installed and in your PATH
shnsplit:          + this file may be unsupported, truncated or corrupt
shnsplit: error: cannot continue due to error(s) shown above
```

Comment: On Debian Buster, adding debian-multimedia.org repository and installing `monkeys-audio` package did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[unflac](https://git.sr.ht/%7Eft/unflac) automatically splits into `flac` and also does the tagging right!

You need `go` installed and then run it by giving the `cue` as input: `~/go/bin/unflac filename.cue`.

I found out about it after files I split with other tools where not playable.