# Splitting a flac from a cuesheet metadata block

Tags: command-line, audio, flac

Some flac files apparently have a “[cuesheet metadata block](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_flac.html#flac_options_cuesheet)”. I know how to split flacs files with `shnsplit` when I have a separate cuesheet at hand (cf. “[How do I split a flac with a cue?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/how-do-i-split-a-flac-with-a-cue)”), but how do I split a flac when the cuesheet is stored inside a metadata block of the flac file?

Command-line preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exporting the cue-sheet to a file first.  For example, `metaflac` has an `--export-cuesheet-to=FILE` option.

From `man metaflac`:

> Export CUESHEET block to a cuesheet file, suitable for use by CD 
>   authoring  software.   Use '-' for stdout.  Only one FLAC file may be
>   specified on the command line.

For example:

```
f='file.flac'
bn=$(basename "$f" .flac)
cue="$bn.cue"

[ ! -e "$cue" ] && metaflac --export-cuesheet-to="$cue" "$f"
shnsplit -f "$cue" -t '%n-%t' -o flac "$f"
```

Comment: When I try this method the exported cue lacks title data which results in split files like `01-.flac`. Is there a way to extract the cue with the titles embedded (because `shnsplit` uses the titles from the cue) ?